# Spring security 6.x logout not working/redirect problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring Security 6, there is an issue where the logout process doesn't work as expected and keeps redirecting.

Why does the logout filter get triggered when navigating to the login page?

Here are the Spring Security configuration and trace logs.

```
CharacterEncodingFilter characterFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

    http
        .addFilterBefore(characterFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests((request) ->
            request
                .requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/oms-manager").hasAnyAuthority(
                    "ROLE_SUPER",
                    "ROLE_ADMIN",
                    "ROLE_EMP",
                    "ROLE_SV",
                    "ROLE_MASTER"
                )
                .requestMatchers("/oms-manager/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                    .formLogin(formLoginConfigurer ->
                        formLoginConfigurer
                            .usernameParameter("userId")
                            .passwordParameter("userPw")
                            .loginPage("/oms-manager/login").permitAll()
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/oms-manager/login/j_spring_security_check")
                            .failureUrl("/oms-manager/login").permitAll()
                                    .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                                    .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
                    )
                    .logout(logoutConfigurer ->
                            logoutConfigurer.logoutUrl("/oms-manager/logout")
                                    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
                                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/oms-manager/login?frominfo=Y").permitAll()
                    )
                    .httpBasic(withDefaults());

            return http.build();`
```

**Error:**

> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.313+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request
> against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request,
> Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@200cc57a,
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2f651899,
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@776bec59,
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@60e3a4d1,
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter@64eae316,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3739e6bb,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7c56f259,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@76c9d7d1,
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5dc8bdd5,
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@62202d8c,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5c25c705,
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@eb63c3c,
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@6ddc575d]]
> (1/1) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.313+09:00 DEBUG 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET
> /oms-manager/logout 2023-10-13T14:10:25.313+09:00 TRACE 30504 ---
> [io-18089-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.313+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.313+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.313+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.313+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking CharacterEncodingFilter (5/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.313+09:00
> TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.314+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository :
> Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession
> f7f740c8-d3fc-4318-82a4-beb8ef036e50 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
> session attribute 2023-10-13T14:10:25.314+09:00 TRACE 30504 ---
> [io-18089-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created
> SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.314+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3]
> .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl
> [Null authentication] 2023-10-13T14:10:25.314+09:00 DEBUG 30504 ---
> [io-18089-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Logging
> out [null] 2023-10-13T14:10:25.314+09:00 DEBUG 30504 ---
> [io-18089-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler :
> Invalidated session f7f740c8-d3fc-4318-82a4-beb8ef036e50
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.314+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-3]
> o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header
> since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request
> against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request,
> Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@200cc57a,
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2f651899,
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@776bec59,
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@60e3a4d1,
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter@64eae316,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3739e6bb,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7c56f259,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@76c9d7d1,
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5dc8bdd5,
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@62202d8c,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5c25c705,
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@eb63c3c,
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@6ddc575d]]
> (1/1) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 DEBUG 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET
> /oms-manager/login 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE 30504 ---
> [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking CharacterEncodingFilter (5/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00
> TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            :
> Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/oms-manager/logout', GET],
> Ant [pattern='/oms-manager/logout', POST], Ant
> [pattern='/oms-manager/logout', PUT], Ant
> [pattern='/oms-manager/logout', DELETE]] 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00
> TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/13)
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to
> Ant [pattern='/oms-manager/login/j_spring_security_check', POST]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> BasicAuthenticationFilter (8/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  :
> Found username 'ADMIN' in Basic Authorization header
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently
> exists 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl
> [Null authentication] 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE 30504 ---
> [io-18089-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created
> SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.317+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with
> GeoAuthenticationProvider (1/1) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00 DEBUG
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  :
> Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
> [Principal=net.geoize.erp10.admin.config.security.user.SrmUser
> [Username=ADMIN, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true,
> AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true,
> AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_SUPER]],
> Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true,
> Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
> SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_SUPER]]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> RequestCacheAwareFilter (9/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        :
> matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to
> lookup a value, but not provided 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (10/13)
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (11/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00
> TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> AuthorizationFilter (13/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00 TRACE 30504
> --- [io-18089-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@18d7c946]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on
> SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@18d7c946]
> using
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1427/0x00000008016bae88@c3a389e
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.390+09:00 DEBUG 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET
> /oms-manager/login 2023-10-13T14:10:25.391+09:00 TRACE 30504 ---
> [io-18089-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not
> set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated
> UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
> [Principal=net.geoize.erp10.admin.config.security.user.SrmUser
> [Username=ADMIN, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true,
> AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true,
> AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_SUPER]],
> Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true,
> Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
> SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_SUPER]]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.391+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-1]
> o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header
> since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request
> against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request,
> Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@200cc57a,
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2f651899,
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@776bec59,
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@60e3a4d1,
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter@64eae316,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3739e6bb,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7c56f259,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@76c9d7d1,
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5dc8bdd5,
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@62202d8c,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5c25c705,
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@eb63c3c,
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@6ddc575d]]
> (1/1) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 DEBUG 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /oms-manager
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking CharacterEncodingFilter (5/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00
> TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            :
> Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/oms-manager/logout', GET],
> Ant [pattern='/oms-manager/logout', POST], Ant
> [pattern='/oms-manager/logout', PUT], Ant
> [pattern='/oms-manager/logout', DELETE]] 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00
> TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/13)
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to
> Ant [pattern='/oms-manager/login/j_spring_security_check', POST]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> BasicAuthenticationFilter (8/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  :
> Did not process authentication request since failed to find username
> and password in Basic Authorization header
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> RequestCacheAwareFilter (9/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        :
> matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to
> lookup a value, but not provided 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
> Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (10/13)
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.394+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (11/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.395+09:00
> TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.395+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking
> AuthorizationFilter (13/13) 2023-10-13T14:10:25.395+09:00 TRACE 30504
> --- [io-18089-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2470281e]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.395+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on
> SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2470281e]
> using AuthorityAuthorizationManager[authorities=[ROLE_SV, ROLE_MASTER,
> ROLE_SUPER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_EMP]] 2023-10-13T14:10:25.395+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository :
> Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession
> f111c182-d0f6-4563-999e-429da4f299d1 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
> session attribute 2023-10-13T14:10:25.395+09:00 TRACE 30504 ---
> [io-18089-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created
> SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
> 2023-10-13T14:10:25.395+09:00 TRACE 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2]
> .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl
> [Null authentication] 2023-10-13T14:10:25.395+09:00 TRACE 30504 ---
> [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set
> SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken
> [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true,
> Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
> SessionId=f111c182-d0f6-4563-999e-429da4f299d1], Granted
> Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] 2023-10-13T14:10:25.395+09:00 TRACE
> 30504 --- [io-18089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     :
> Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser,
> Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true,
> Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
> SessionId=f111c182-d0f6-4563-999e-429da4f299d1], Granted
> Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since
> access is denied
>
> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access
> Denied

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFPdL.png)

I have tried excluding the custom handler, but the same issue persists with both Redis and Spring Session.

Comment: I find same issue. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12750

I removed httpbasic